# how to send an Alert() event after reached the stop loss price using trailing stop?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to send an alert message using webhook to 3commas, it is working for entry operations, but I can't capture the event of closing the position and send the alert message properly.

I'm using the next code to trigger the close of the opened position

```
if (strategy.position_size > 0) 
    strategy.exit(id="XL TRL STP", stop=longStopPrice)
```

longStopPrice is calculated by code and when the live price reaches this value the command `strategy.exit` is executed properly

But I don know how to send in that particular moment the alert to 3commas and not at the closes of the bar.

Can anybody help me with this?

thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Add the alert_loss parameter in your strategy.exit function

```
if (strategy.position_size > 0) 
    strategy.exit(id="XL TRL STP", stop=longStopPrice, alert_loss = "XL TRL STP")
```

Then, when creating the alerts, select the "order fills only" condition.
The SL alert will fire in real-time and not on candle close.

2/ Make sure the correct properties features are unselected.
I'm really not sure about it but this could maybe make a difference.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRh8M.jpg

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! in alert_loss = "XL TRL STP" ¿should i replace "XL TRL STP" for the message to 3commas?

Comment: correct indeed, that's the part that needs to be changed with your 3 commas "stop deal" command message